# Custom user panel in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Secenario is that website has an admin for website in wordpress and users
can only post/edit their posts.


User panel is diffrent form main theme (its default gray one).
Is there a way to write a custom user panel that would work with wordpress
login and that would look like main site, having  only post/edit/logout functions?

Comment: do you want another css style for the dashboard (admin area), or do you just want to restrict users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can change how your dashboard looks. 
on how to change the style of dashboard - take a look [**here**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes).
on how to restrict user access to only certain parts of the dashboard - you can do that easily with the [**capability manager**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capsman/) plugin.